# response of server with json return a html tag

Tags: android, json

I am using below function to send a string value to the server but the return value is :

```
<html><html>
```

> 07-10 19:55:20.565: E/result(23924): < HTML> < /HTML>

---

my function is :

```
public static String POST(String url, String person){
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String result = "";
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        String json = "";

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(person, person);

        json = jsonObject.toString();


        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);

        httpPost.setEntity(se);

        httpPost.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPost.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);

        inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();


        if(inputStream != null)
            result = convertInputStreamToString(inputStream);
        else
            result = "Did not work!";

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("InputsStream", e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

    // 11. return result
    Log.e("result", result);
    return result;
}

private static String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
    String line = "";
    String result = "";
    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        result += line;

    inputStream.close();

    return result;

}
```

the return values must be : 1 or -1 or 0 .

what is my problem ?

Comment: May be the problem at server side. check the code over there.

Comment: now I am using Volley lib and it works fine...